# Unlimites subcategory in a single table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have a category table like this

```
id  |   parentId    |   category

1   |   0           |   sports  
2   |   1           |   cricket
3   |   2           |   batsman
4   |   0           |   Cinima
5   |   4           |   Bolywood
6   |   5           |   Actor
```

And an item table like this

```
id  |   categoryId  |   item

1   |   3           |   Sachin  
2   |   6           |   Amirkhan
```

I want to select the item and relate it with its parent categories.
for eg i want to print a result as

```
Sachin(batsman-cricket-sports)

Amirkhan(actor-bollywood-cinima)
```

I have unlimited number of subcategories and can i select all thse in a single query using php and laravel.(i don't likes to use a third relation table for keeping category-subcategory relationship)
Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the Options for Storing Hierarchical Data in a Relational Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: I haven't read the above article, but I would advise you to change your schema so that it is easier to identify the _groups_ into which each category falls.  As it stands now, you're going to need Gordon Linoff to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [plugin](https://github.com/AdrianSkierniewski/eloquent-tree).
This what You are doing is called tree behaviour, or tree model. It is not popular, becouse saving is quick, but read quite slow. Add to composer, require and have a nice day

Comment: Actually i don't likes to use an external plugin.I just wants to code it in ordinary way.